# What is --without-x option for?

Tags: gcc, gcc4

I have a gcc compiler v 4.2.2 with next build options :

```
$ /opt/eldk-4.2/usr/bin/ppc_6xx-gcc -v
Reading specs from /home/dejovivl/workspace/eldk-4.2/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/powerpc-linux/4.2.2/specs
Target: powerpc-linux
Configured with: /opt/eldk/build/ppc-2008-04-01/work/usr/src/denx/BUILD/crosstool-0.43/build/gcc-4.2.2-glibc-20070515T2025-eldk/powerpc-linux/gcc-4.2.2/configure --target=powerpc-linux --host=i686-host_pc-linux-gnu --prefix=/var/tmp/eldk.UZpAG7/usr/crosstool/gcc-4.2.2-glibc-20070515T2025-eldk/powerpc-linux --disable-hosted-libstdcxx --with-headers=/var/tmp/eldk.UZpAG7/usr/crosstool/gcc-4.2.2-glibc-20070515T2025-eldk/powerpc-linux/powerpc-linux/include --with-local-prefix=/var/tmp/eldk.UZpAG7/usr/crosstool/gcc-4.2.2-glibc-20070515T2025-eldk/powerpc-linux/powerpc-linux --disable-nls --enable-threads=posix --enable-symvers=gnu --enable-__cxa_atexit --enable-languages=c,c++,java --enable-shared --enable-c99 --enable-long-long --without-x
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.2.2
```

Most options are easy to find, except for `--without-x`. So, what is this option for?

The [summary of gcc options](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Option-Summary.html) didn't help, since the option is not listed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Configure options are not options to `gcc`. They are given when gcc is built to the configure script. To find out what they mean, check the gcc source documentation.

If `--with-x` is not there, it doesn't have to mean anything, as autoconf-generated configure scripts can ignore flags.

However, it is listed on http://gcc.gnu.org/install/configure.html -

> --with-x
>
> Use the X Window System.

Comment: cool. thanks. I am searching for the last 30 minutes without success